# Flash Equivalent for iPhone

Tags: iphone, flash, flash-cs4

Anyone know of any flash equivalent software for the iPhone. Need to do some simple masking, animation...

Comment: Apple would obviously tell you that HTML/CSS/JavaScript is the Flash equivalent for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout Adobe's AIR. Its a run time that runs on the iPhone. You write in their flash language and then same code can run on iOS and Android.

Comment: Is that within browsers or for app dev?

Comment: app dev, believe it or not. Check it out http://www.adobe.com/products/air/http://www.adobe.com/products/air/. Pretty cool. Apple apparently changed their tune and allows this kind of thing now. (+1 please).

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can use AIR, but I'm guessing you want this to run in the browser, not as some native app.  That is, you want something you can put on a web page, not distribute as an application through the App Store.

If that is the case, try Wallaby:  http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/

Wallaby can export certain Flash features to HTML5, which can be rendered in mobile Safari.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact needs (eg. if you want to work with timeline animations) then using the iOS packager part of AIR is a good option. For most uses however I would consider the performance of Flash iOS apps to be sub-par.

A development tool that is fairly similar to Flash programming-wise is Corona SDK:
http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/